# Show convergence of sequence $\frac{\ln n}{n^p}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I just learned about the Cauchy Criterion for convergence of a sequence:

> **Theorem**: The sequence $\{ s_n \}^\infty_{n=1}$ converges if the difference $s_n-s_m$ approaches zero as both $m$ and $n$ approach infinity.

I tried to use this to test for the convergence of $$\{ s_n \}^\infty_{n=1}=\{\frac{\ln n}{n^p} \}^\infty_{n=1}$$
where $p$ is a positive number.

Following the theorem, I wrote
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n^p}-\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\ln m}{m^p}=0,$$
hence the sequence is convergent.

I realised that I am doing something wrong, since I'm subtracting the same things here. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Use the inequality $\ln n=q \ln n^{1/q} <qn^{1/q}$ where $q >1/p$

Comment: To apply the Cauchy theorem you have to show that $$\left|\frac{\ln (n)}{n^p} - \frac{\ln (m)}{m^p}\right|$$ becomes arbitrarily small if only $n$ and $m$ are large enough.

Comment: Your last equation would be valid—*if* you already knew that the limit exists; but that's what we're trying to prove. Thomas's comment is the best approach.

Comment: I may be completely off-beam, but it seems to me that the easiest way to show that the Cauchy criterion is satisfied, in this case, is to show that $s_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty.$ Because the Cauchy criterion is automatically satisfied by any convergent sequence, and because the limit of this particular sequence is known, it would seem odd if you were asked to prove that the criterion is satisfied without proving that the limit is zero. Was it set as an exercise, or it a question you are asking yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prove that the sequence converges is $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln n}{n^p} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/n}{pn^{p-1}} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{pn^p} =0.$$

To use the Cauchy criterion, first suppose $p > 1$ and we fix $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $N$ large such that $N^{p-1} > 2/\epsilon$ and have $n\geq m > N$ so that $$\left\vert \frac{\ln n }{n^p} - \frac{\ln m}{m^p} \right \vert  \leq \frac{\ln n }{n^p} + \frac{\ln m}{m^p} \leq \frac{n}{n^p} + \frac{m}{m^p} = \frac{1}{n^{p-1}} + \frac{1}{m^{p-1}} \leq \frac{2}{N^{p-1}} < \epsilon.$$

For $p \leq 1$, choose a $q$ such that $p \geq 1/q$. Now fix $\epsilon > 0$ and $N$ large such that $N^{p-1/q} > 2q/\epsilon$ and have $n\geq m > N$ so that $$\left\vert \frac{\ln n }{n^p} - \frac{\ln m}{m^p} \right \vert  \leq \frac{\ln n }{n^p} + \frac{\ln m}{m^p} = \frac{q \ln n^{1/q}}{n^p} + \frac{q\ln m^{1/q}}{m^p} \leq \frac{qn^{1/q}}{n^p} + \frac{qm^{1/q}}{m^p} \leq \frac{2q}{N^{p-1/q}} < \epsilon.$$

Hence $\{\frac{\ln(n)}{n^p}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Note that the second case doesn't really require the $p\leq 1$. We could remove this and realize the first case is a special case of the second argument where $q=1$.